# Structure two different websites where external pages are different, internal pages are same

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.Net MVC website, "learning Mandarin online".  It's operational and it's working fine for me.   Now, I want to reuse this website as a template for a new website, "learning Spanish online." Both websites will be on completely different domains and on a completely different servers.

For my "learning Mandarin online" website, **1/3 of the webpages are *external* pages that the user can browse without logging into the website**.   **The other 2/3 of the webpages are *internal* pages that the user can only see if they login to the website**.  I want **both websites to use different external pages** (the external .aspx pages will be different for both sites) but **both websites to share the same set of internal pages** (the internal .aspx pages will be the same for both websites).

My question is, in ASP.Net MVC, how can I structure my project/solution for both websites?  Since the only difference for both websites are the external pages, the easiest solution I can think of to handle the external pages is storing the mappings for each view in the database, fetching this mapping from the database based on some constant (ie. WebsiteType) set in web.config, and then returning the view based on the mapping.  For example, in my controller:

```
// WebsiteType is stored in web.config.  It is set to LearnMandarin for the learn Manadarin
// online website and it is set to LearnSpanish for the learn Spanish online website
string websiteType = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteType"];

// figure out which Homepage .aspx view to return, based on the websiteType
// GetView(...) will get the mapping from the database
string viewToReturn = GetView(websiteType, "HomepageView");

return View(viewToReturn);
```

This is the cleanest solution I can think of so far and the best structure I can think of.  I would end up having two different .aspx files in the same directory - one .aspx page for the learning Mandarin online website, another.aspx file for the learning Spanish online website.  Is this the best way to structure my project or is there an even cleaner way?

(I am using Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.Net MVC version 3.0.0.0)

Comment: This is really what the *Area* feature of MVC has been created for!

Comment: So, are you saying my external pages, should be under Areas whereas my internal pages that are shared, should not be under Areas?  I'm new to using Areas, so my apologies if I am not up to speed (I'm reading it tutorials on it right now).

Comment: You could create an attribute to set the Area RequestContext data based on the website domain or some other factor, and then place pages where you see fit.

Comment: Ok, cool  Let me study up RequestContext and how I can apply it to Areas.  Also, if somebody can provide a more detailed answer that Haney is suggesting, that would be appreciated since I'm trying to figure out how Areas and RequestContext can both be used to solve my problem and I'm new using Areas and RequestContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I more or less used Areas as Haney suggested.  I created an area called SpanishTutor in my project.  Once you create the area, it will have the same controller and view folder structure as a typical ASP.Net MVC project (but it will be all under the Areas sub folder).  I consider my homepage as one of my "external" pages.  Thus, I create a HomeController.cs file in the "controller" folder under in my SpanishTutor area.  For this HomeControllers.cs file, I had to change the namespace to "Tutors.Areas.SpanishTutor.Controllers" so that it doesn't conflict with the existing HomeController.cs file.  I also create a Home folder with Index.aspx under the "views" folder in my SpanishTutor area.

Next, I needed to register the routing for my "learn Spanish online" homepage to override the routing of my "learn Mandarin online" homepage.  When you create the SpanishTutor area, a .cs file is created called SpanishTutorAreaRegistration.cs.  In that file, add the following code to RegisterArea(...):

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{

  string websiteType = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteType"];

  if (websiteType.Contains("spanishtutor"))
  {
    context.MapRoute(
        "SpanishTutor_Root", // Route name
        "", // override the homepage
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "Tutors.Areas.SpanishTutor.Controllers" } // namespace so there is no conflict with the namespace of the original homeapge
    );
  }
}
```

If you have more external webpages, you can add each external webpage just like the homepage.  For me, there was no need to modify Global.asax.cs.

In my web.config, add the following (I can change it to "mandarintutor" for the "learn Mandarin online" website):

```
 <add key="WebsiteType" value="spanishtutor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would agree with @Haney, to an extent. It really depends on how different the Mandarin/Spanish protected sections of the site are. In general, the division between protected and unprotected sections is simple. Controllers/Actions available to only logged in users should be protected with the `[Authorize]` attribute. To do something like restrict a user who only signed up for Mandarin to the Mandarin section, for example, you would use roles. Assign the user to a "Mandarin" role, for example, and then specify that only users in that role can access it: `[Authorize(Roles = "Mandarin")]`.

Where it starts to get more iffy is with the distinction between the Mandarin and Spanish sections. For most things, you could actually make the language a route parameter. In other words, all Mandarin pages would have a URL like `/mandarin/some/page/`, while Spanish pages would have a URL like `/spanish/some/page/`. You can use the route parameter, then, to switch out layouts, branch inside actions or view, etc. However, if there are a lot of difference between these two sections, all this branching could lead to some complicated code. If that becomes the case, then it might be more appropriate to create each language as a separate area. Each area will get a segregated routing scheme, i.e. if your area is named `Mandarin`, then every controller action in that area would automatically be under a URL like `/mandarin/some/page/`. You wouldn't have to capture the "mandarin" part of the route to determine the language in play: simply by hitting a controller action within that area, you would know. However, the downside to this approach is that you could end up with some code duplication. You can prevent most of that by controller and view inheritance, but there may be situations where you still end with very similar code existing in both areas.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I figured it out.  Please look at the solution I posted.  Thanks for your help!